# elasticsearch river fails for large set of data

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-river

I have an issue with river set up in elasticsearch with mongodb. I have no problem to import data from mongodb if the size of date is within a million. But when the data are large with 10 million or greater the river just fails to index all the records from mongodb collection.

I see this error in the log

```
org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.Slurper$SlurperException: River out of sync with oplog.rs collection
    at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.Slurper.isRiverStale(Slurper.java:618)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.Slurper.oplogCursor(Slurper.java:603)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.Slurper.run(Slurper.java:119)
```

And usually says river-stale as the error few times. Also I have a oplog size as 1024MB in my mongodb setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why is the River stale / out of sync?

You are writing data to the [replication oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) faster than the ElasticSearch river can process it, and need to [increase the size of your oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/).

If the River processing falls too far behind, the `oplog` tailable cursor will become "stale" meaning that the River no longer has a point in common with your MongoDB server (i.e. it is "out of sync"). To ensure you've indexed all documents, you would have to fully resync the River rather than just resuming from the new documents being inserted/updated. Otherwise your River will miss some document changes written while it was out of sync with the oplog.

#### How big should my MongoDB oplog be?

The [default oplog size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/#oplog-size) is 5% of free disk space in a 64-bit Linux server environment. 1024Mb is a very small oplog size if you are pushing through tens of millions of updates and also need to sync those to your external ElasticSearch server. Your performance issue may be exacerbated if ElasticSearch is running on the same server as MongoDB.

You can get an estimate of the duration covered by your oplog in the `mongo` shell using:

```
db.printReplicationInfo()
```

Note that this is an estimate based on the first and last entry observed in your oplog. If you process a large volume of changes in a short period of time the oplog duration can be significantly reduced.

You could make a guesstimate on appropriate oplog sizing, but a better approach would be to use a monitoring system like [MMS (MongoDB Management Service)](https://mms.mongodb.com) to capture some historical activity. In particular, look at activity in the `Replication Oplog Window` and `Oplog Db/Hour` stats calculated in MMS. [Other MongoDB-aware monitoring systems](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/monitoring/) should ideally have similar calculated stats.